# LINQ query where List should contain ALL elements of another List not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have many to many relationship between Video and Tag entities

Here you can see a few entries in Video table, joint table TagVideo, and Tag table.

Each Video can have multiple Tags and each Tag can have multiple Videos.

Im trying to create a LINQ query, where I can pass in list of Tag's and find all Video's which contain ALL of those tags.

[image: many to many]

This is my LINQ query right now, which I believe should work.

```cs
public async Task<List<CreateVideoWithTagNamesDTO>> FindVideosByTag(ICollection<Tag> tags)
{    
    var tagIds = tags.Select(r => r.Id).ToArray();
    var result = await _db
        .Where(p => p.Tags
            .Select(r => r.Id)
            .All(tag => tagIds.Contains(tag)))
        .Select(item => new CreateVideoWithTagNamesDTO
        {
            Description = item.Description,
            Title = item.Title,
            Url = item.Url,
            Tags = _mapper.Map<IList<CreateTagDTO>>(item.Tags)
        })
        .ToListAsync();   
    
    return result;    
}
```

However this is not working properly, here are some queries I did.
First I sent just a single Tag named "Pin" and there is a Video which does have a "Pin" tag. So I should get this video, however I dont get any Videos back

[image: pin tag]

Debugger shows all incoming values correct.

[image: debugger]

When I query with 2 tags, "Pin" and "Passing" i get back all 3 videos, which Is not correct. As only one video has both tags so Im expecting that video.

[image: pin and pass]

Finally, when I query only with "Passing" I get 2 correct videos which have only Passing tag

[image: passing only]

How do I correct query to only select videos which have correct input tags?

Comment: I think, you're `Where()` is the wrong way around. Try: `.Where(p => tagIds.All(id => p.Tags.Any(t => t.Id == id)))`.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride not sure that this will translate. Maybe join with count will do the trick (assuming that tag can be added to video only one time)

Comment: Which version of EF Core are you using?

Comment: @GuruStron I think it will translate, but yeah there is probably a way to do this which will generate better SQL.

Comment: Anyway the mistake in the query I pointed out does not explain why you won't get any results when asking for all videos with the tag "Pin".

Comment: Another issue might be that the `Tags` are not loaded with the entity. Be aware that `All()` returns true for an empty collection regardless of its condition.

Comment: EF Core 6.0.7 @GuruStron

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I tried your version, which gives me an exeption "The LINQ expression 'id => DbSet<Dictionary<string, object>>("TagVideo")"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following query:

```cs
var tagIds = tags.Select(r => r.Id).ToArray();
var tagCount = tagIds.Length;

var result = await _db.Videos
   .Where(p => p.Tags.Where(t => tagIds.Contains(t.Id)).Count() == tagCount)
   .Select(...)
```

Comment: `Where(t => tagIds.Contains(t.Id)).Count()` could be simplified to `Count(t => tagIds.Contains(t.Id))`.

Comment: I know, not so easy to type in iPad.

Comment: Thank you, I was going crazy with this!!!! Simple and makes sense .